# For loop over several arguments with different length each

Tags: list-manipulation, files-and-directories

I have a set of text files named in indexed way d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6, d7, d8, d9.

I want to read them by Mathematica and export them back with other index names N(s1f1+s1f1), N(s1f1+s2f2), N(s1f1+s3f3),N(s2f2+s1f1), N(s2f2+s2f2), N(s2f2+s3f3),N(s3f3+s1f1), N(s3f3+s2f2), N(s3f3+s3f3)

I did a for loop as follows

```
 For[i = 1, i <= 3, i++, 
  For[j = 1, j <= 3, j++, 
   For[k = 1, k <= 3, k++, 
    Export[StringJoin["N", "(", "s", TextString[i], "f", 
      TextString[i], "+", "s", TextString[j], "f", TextString[j], ")",
       ".txt"], Import[StringJoin["d", TextString[k], ".txt"]]]]]];
```

But the problem is the resulting files contain data from d9 only

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't need to import and export files just to rename them. You can just use [`RenameFile`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RenameFile.html) to carry out the renaming for you.
2. `For` loops, and procedural loops in general, are not recommended in Mathematica; see [Alternatives to procedural loops and iterating over lists in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7924/27951) and [Why should I avoid the For loop in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/134609/27951).

Here is an alternative to explicit procedural looping that uses [`Table`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html)and [`MapThread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapThread.html) to feed the names to `RenameFile`:

```
MapThread[
  RenameFile[Echo@#1, Echo@#2] &,
  {
    Table[StringJoin["d", k, ".txt"], {k, CharacterRange["1", "9"]}],
    Table[
      StringJoin["N", "(s", i, "f", i, "+s", j, "f", j, ").txt"],
      {i, CharacterRange["1", "3"]}, {j, CharacterRange["1", "3"]}
    ]~Flatten~1
  }
]
```

I also avoid the conversions of the numbers to strings (which, by the way, would be more conveniently carreid out by [`ToString`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToString.html) rather than `TextString`) by providing the string numerals instead of the numbers as values of the iterators in the `Table`s.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works well now

Comment: @AmrSaleh You are very welcome. If you think that my answer solves your problem, you can also upvote it / accept it by ticking the gray checkmark close to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the filenames you need using `Table`:

```
filenames = Flatten[Table[{StringJoin @ MapThread[Riffle, 
     {{{"N(s", "f", "+"}, {"s", "f", ").txt"}}, ToString /@ {i, j}}],
    StringJoin["d", TextString[j + 3 (i - 1)], ".txt"]},
  {i, 3}, {j, 3}], 1]
```

> ```
> {{"N(s1f1+s1f1).txt", "d1.txt"}, 
>  {"N(s1f1+s2f2).txt", "d2.txt"},
>  {"N(s1f1+s3f3).txt", "d3.txt"}, 
>  {"N(s2f2+s1f1).txt", "d4.txt"},
>  {"N(s2f2+s2f2).txt", "d5.txt"},
>  {"N(s2f2+s3f3).txt", "d6.txt"},
>  {"N(s3f3+s1f1).txt", "d7.txt"},
>  {"N(s3f3+s2f2).txt", "d8.txt"}, 
>  {"N(s3f3+s3f3).txt", "d9.txt"}}
> ```

Then use

```
Export[#, Import@#2] & @@@ filenames
```

Comment: Thank you for help

Comment: @AmrSaleh, you are most welcome.